# grub - Keyboard stuck in GRUB

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, keyboard, grub

I have dual booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. I have Intel DH67BL motherboard which does not support PS/2 keyboard,mouse and am using Logitech K120 USB 2.0 keyboard.
I have set GRUB to load Windows 7 by default within 10 seconds. But most of the (7/10)time when GRUB loads the keyboard is stuck. I can see the time running out in GRUB. But my keyboard gets stuck in GRUB menu. None of the key work(not even NumLock key).
But the keyboard works perfectly in BIOS, Windows Bootloader and all other boot programs. So what I am thinking is that, the problem is in GRUB. After searching a lot, here is list what I have tried:
1) Set USB Legacy Support Enable in BIOS 
2) Changed USB port of keyboard

None of above solution work
Is there any alternative to GRUB which support dual boot. I have heard about UEFI bootloaders. Is it also a bootloader like GRUB? If yes how can I use it?
I am tired of this problem. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after trying different solutions my problem got solved.
I replaced GRUB2 with BURG. See [here](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-boot-loader-in-ubuntu-1304-and-linuxmint/) for install instructions